# Counting sum of lines in all .c and .h files

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a shell script that will count the sum of all lines in every file in a directory (and its subdirectories) of format `.c` and `.h`.

I already have that code but I am not sure how to make it find both file formats.

```
!/bin/bash
#Program
total=0
find /path -type f -name "*.php" | while read FILE; do
     count=$(grep -c ^ < "$FILE")
     echo "$FILE has $count lines"
     let total=total+count 
done
echo TOTAL LINES COUNTED:  $total
```

I am newbie to shell/bash and if anything else is wrong I would be grateful for help.

Comment: You can `cat` all the files you found and count the output with a single `wc -l` outside the loop - at least that's what I usually do.

Comment: Ok for a Shell exercise, otherwise if you really have to count lines of code you have the excellent, **cloc** utility https://linuxconfig.org/counting-lines-of-code-with-cloc

Comment: Notice that the shebang line should be `#!/bin/bash` instead of `!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 4):

**Optimized** and **fast** **`find`** + GNU **`parallel`** solution:

```
find /path -type f -name "*.[ch]" -print0 | parallel -q0 -j0 --no-notice  wc -l {} \
| awk '{ sum+=$1 }END{ print "TOTAL LINES COUNTED: "sum }'
```

---

- `-print0` - print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a null character  (instead  of  the  newline character  that `-print` uses). This allows file names that contain newlines or other types of white space to be              correctly interpreted by programs that process the **`find`** output.
- with `parallel` the command `wc -l {}` will be excuted for each file **in parallel** (that's called parallel processing)

Comment: I think this one, without the `tail -1`, is what fits OP's request best (regarding those echoes).

Comment: it sums the number of lines of the files in the same batch, but i don't think you sum the numbers if there are multiple lines get output.

Comment: `-exec cmd +` will run `cmd` on as many files as possible by the argument length limits of the shell. If there are more files, it will run `cmd` more than once. It will run as many times as necessary. Consequently, if there are too many files, `wc -l` will run multiple times, once per each group, and then you'll get sub-total counts, which would need to be reconciled to get the equivalent of OP's code

Comment: Also note that `wc -l` counts lines differently from `grep -c ^` :-/

Answer (score 2):

To find `.c` and `.h` files instead of `.php`,
simply change the value of the `-name` parameter to `*.[ch]`.

There are a few other issues in the script:

- It would be safer to read the filenames as `IFS= read -r`
- The first line should be `#!/bin/bash` instead of `!/bin/bash`

And some minor improvements are possible:

- The summing logic can be written a bit simpler using `((...))` syntax (arithmetic context)
- It's not recommended to use uppercase variable names, as that conversion is reserved to system variables

Putting it together:

```
#!/bin/bash

total=0
find /path -type f -name "*.[ch]" | while IFS= read -r file; do
     count=$(grep -c ^ < "$file")
     echo "$file has $count lines"
     ((total += count))
done
echo TOTAL LINES COUNTED:  $total
```

Other answers recommend variations of `find ... -exec wc -l`.
Although they look more elegant,
they will not work exactly the same way as your script:

- `wc -l` counts lines a bit differently from `grep -c ^`. In particular it doesn't count the last line of a file if it doesn't end with a newline. Try for example `printf hello > file; wc -l file; grep -c ^ file` -> you'll get 0 and 1.
- Getting the line count in the individual files, and the total lines is not so simple. Using `find ... -exec wc -l {} +` comes quite close (if your implementation of `find` supports `+`), but again there will be corner cases that need special treatment. For example if there are too many files, then `wc` will be invoked multiple times, producing multiple sub-totals that would need to be reconciled.

Comment: @yacc the reason is word splitting on white space, and other special characters in the filenames in the output of `$(find ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cat $(find /path -type f \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' \)) |wc -l
```

It will run `cat` on every file returned by `find` and pipe the output into `wc`. If you need the value in a variable just do this

```
lines=$(cat ...)
echo counted $lines lines
```

Comment: the total size of the command line is limited and the generated list may not fit. this also runs into trouble with stuff with spaces etc. the best way is to pipe to | xargs -0. see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind i did not downvote, i do suggest you just remove this answer though

Comment: i think a more encouraged way is to use `-exec` of the find command, so the interpolation can be dropped.

Comment: All of your remarks are valid. I confess it's sort of hacky style that I usually work with. But on normal conditions you won't get close to maximum line length and such.

Comment: It is true you can get away with it most of the time, but there is no reason to do it this way. Just do it the right way. @HuStmpHrrr it's fine to -exec, but it prevents running wc in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Cat all files ending in `.c` or `.h` and pipe to `grep -c`:

```
find -type f -name '*.[ch]' -exec cat {} + | grep -c '^'
```

For a find without the `+` option, the alternative is

```
find -type f -name '*.[ch]' -exec cat {} \; | grep -c '^'
```

which calls `cat` once per file instead of as few times as possible, making it a bit slower.

If you know that you won't have a lot of files approaching the command line length limit, you could use just shell globbing:

```
shopt -s globstar # enable **/* glob
cat **/*.[ch] | grep -c '^'
```